# JSF+Facelets treating bean action as property

Tags: jsf, facelets, managed, el, javabeans

Guys, for some reason EL is not telling actions from properties. I have this page test.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<body>

<form action="#{TestBean.test}">
    <p>#{TestBean.status}</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Test Again"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

TestBean.status is a string property (there is a getStatus method) and TestBean.test is a method which return "sucess".

Every time I call the page I get this exception:

```
ERROR [STDERR] 05/08/2009 17:41:07 com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/etc/test/test.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /etc/test/test.xhtml: Bean: test.TestBean, property: test
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:53)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:39)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.encodeRecursive(ComponentSupport.java:232)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.encodeRecursive(ComponentSupport.java:239)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:580)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:108)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:216)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:384)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Maybe it's a long shot, I can describe better my environment. But at first glance, any tips?

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was forgetting the jsfc attribute.

It should be:

```
<form **jsfc="h:form"** action="#{TestCaseBean.test}">
```

tks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, EL does not have a syntax to invoke an arbitrary method.  The syntax you're using, when applied to anything other than a `Map`, `List`, or array, will look for a property getter corresponding to the name; the dot is syntactic sugar for `TestBean["test"]`.

While it is possible to define custom *functions* for EL as part of a JSP tag library, they must be implemented by static methods.  See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) for more information on how to do so.

This feature is [currently in the JSR pipeline](http://blogs.oracle.com/kchung/entry/jsr_245_mr_part_i) however.